# Setting hyperlink field in SP 2010 does not work for view-specific link of InfoPath 2010 form library

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, designer-workflow, form, hyperlink

This is my first question on any stack exchange site, so any recommendations on how to improve asking a question would be tremendously helpful.

The issue I am facing here today is setting a hyperlink field in my InfoPath Form library in SharePoint 2010 through a SPD workflow. **Here's what I know:**

1. How to format a URL properly and use string variables to update the Hyperlink field. I have successfully used:

http://www.google.com, Google

and

```
[%Current Item:Server Relative URL%], [%Current Item:Title%]
```

2. How to create a View-Specific URL for an InfoPath form in an Form library. Ex:

> http://www.example.com/sub/subsub/foo/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=[%CurrentItem:ServerRelativeURL%]&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fsub/subsub/foo%2FFormLibrary%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultView=View&DefaultItemOpen=1

**Now the question is, why is my sharepoint workflow not setting the hyperlink field correctly when using this form link in update list field action like so:**

```
Update Item in Current Item
```

[Image of Update List Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF7Qv.jpg)

```
[%Variable:LinkToForm%], [%Current Item:Title%]
```

where [%Variable:LinkToForm%] contains

> http://www.example.com/sub/subsub/foo/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=[%CurrentItem:ServerRelativeURL%]&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fsub/subsub/foo%2FFormLibrary%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultView=View&DefaultItemOpen=1

*Note: I have also tried to replace [%CurrentItem:ServerRelativeURL%] with [%CurrentItem:URLPath%] and it does not work.*

My Workflow runs on item creation, and the first message in the workflow is this error:

> The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information.

The workflow continues to run, but the hyperlink field is not set and remains empty.

**Perhaps the reason I am trying to do this may be helpful.**

In my form library, I would like to have a different "Default View" of the form depending on where it is being opened from. Since this functionality does not exist in SharePoint, the idea was to create a link to the form with the included view (with &defaultview=view) that would show on the default form library view instead of the original link to the form that SharePoint would create.

**My Permissions**

I am essentially a power user with access to SPD and Limited site admin permissions on my sub-site. I cannot edit default pages.

Has anyone else run across this problem? Any pointers or tips would be appreciated.